# Wix: How to copy .XLL files to Excel's common LIBRARY folder that is Excel version dependent?

Tags: excel, wix, windows-installer, installation

I am new to WiX and trying to create an installer to distribute some Excel add-ins (.XLL files) I created.

I now know how to drop my files in the current user's Excel addins library folder, which has been %AppData%\Microsoft\AddIns for many years and o/s versions now.

However, I also need to copy (but **not** activate) a couple of the .XLL files to Excel's common/shared addins library folder that is Excel version dependent.  e.g. ..\Office**11**\LIBRARY, ..\Office**14**\LIBRARY, etc.

How can I write my script to ensure that my installer will correctly copy the .XLL files to the common/shared "Office**XX**\LIBRARY" folder, regardless of the version of Excel installed?

When I used InstallShield, I relied on the LibraryPath() function in the Excel automation object that could be accessed directly from IS script.

In WiX, am I forced to create a custom action project to access the Excel object in order to read the library path?

Thanks for you time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to solve this without a custom action, although this solution may end up quite verbose if you want to support a lot of different versions of office.  The general idea is to use a `<RegistrySearch.../>` to set a property to the location of a particular version of office.  Then use that property as both a directory location and a condition for a component.

One slight complication: The property used as the *Directory* attribute of the [Directory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368295(v=vs.85).aspx) element should be a copy of the property found by registry search.  If we try and use the same property returned by the registry search, the [Directory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368295(v=vs.85).aspx) element will set the property to the resolved directory location, which will set the condition to true and install the component anyway.

The `<RegistrySearch.../>` for Excel 2010:

```
<!-- Search for Excel 2010 -->
<Property Id="OFFICE14LOCATION">
  <RegistrySearch Id="Office14Location" 
                  Root="HKLM"
                  Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Excel\InstallRoot"
                  Name="Path"
                  Type="raw"/>
</Property>

<!-- Make a copy of the property for the directory reference -->
<SetProperty Id="Office14DirectoryPath" Value="[OFFICE14LOCATION]" Before="CostFinalize"/>
```

The component part for Excel 2010:

```
<!-- Conditionally install MyAddIn.xll to the Office14\Library directory 
     Remember to reference Office14Library in a <Feature> -->
<DirectoryRef Id="Office14Library">
  <Component Id="Office14AddIn" Guid="-- your GUID --">
    <Condition>OFFICE14LOCATION</Condition>
    <File Id="Office14AddIn" Name="MyAddIn.xll" Source="MyAddIn.xll" />
  </Component>
</DirectoryRef>
```

The directory part for Excel 2010:

```
<!-- Note: Include this as a child of <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" ..> -->
<Directory Id="Office14DirectoryPath" Name="Office14"> <!-- Note: The Name attribute is redundant but needed to avoid ICE30 warning -->
  <Directory Id="Office14Library" Name="Library"/>
</Directory>
```

You will need to repeat the above blocks for each version of office supported.

**Excel 2007**

To support Excel 2007 you would change the references to 14 in the above example to 12.  For example:

```
<!-- Search for Excel 2007-->
<Property Id="OFFICE12LOCATION">
  <RegistrySearch Id="Office12Location" 
                  Root="HKLM"
                  Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Excel\InstallRoot"
                  Name="Path"
                  Type="raw"/>
</Property>

<!-- Make a copy of the property for the directory reference -->
<SetProperty Id="Office12DirectoryPath" Value="[OFFICE12LOCATION]" Before="CostFinalize"/>


<!-- Conditionally install MyAddIn.xll to the Office12\Library directory 
     Remember to reference Office12Library in a <Feature> -->
<DirectoryRef Id="Office12Library">
  <Component Id="Office12AddIn" Guid="-- your GUID --">
    <Condition>OFFICE12LOCATION</Condition>
    <File Id="Office12AddIn" Name="MyAddIn.xll" Source="MyAddIn.xll" />
  </Component>
</DirectoryRef>

<!-- Note: Include this as a child of <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" ..> -->
<Directory Id="Office12DirectoryPath" Name="Office12"> <!-- Note: The Name attribute is redundant but needed to avoid ICE30 warning -->
  <Directory Id="Office12Library" Name="Library"/>
</Directory>
```

**64 Bit Excel 2010**

The solution can also be extended to support the 64 bit version of Excel 2010:

The `<RegistrySearch.../>` for 64 bit Excel 2010:

```
<!-- Search for 64 bit Excel 2010 -->
<Property Id="OFFICE14LOCATIONX64">
  <RegistrySearch Id="Office14LocationX64" 
                  Root="HKLM"
                  Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Excel\InstallRoot"
                  Name="Path"
                  Win64="yes"
                  Type="raw"/>
</Property>

<!-- Make a copy of the property for the directory reference -->
<SetProperty Id="Office14DirectoryPathX64" Value="[OFFICE14LOCATIONX64]" Before="CostFinalize"/>
```

The component part for 64 bit Excel 2010:

```
<!-- Conditionally install MyAddIn.xll to the Office14\Library directory 
     Remember to reference Office14Library in a <Feature> -->
<DirectoryRef Id="Office14LibraryX64">
  <Component Id="Office14AddInX64" Win64="yes" Guid="-- your GUID --">
    <Condition>OFFICE14LOCATIONX64</Condition>
    <File Id="Office14AddInX64" Name="MyAddIn.xll" Source="MyAddIn.xll" />
  </Component>
</DirectoryRef>
```

The directory part for 64 bit Excel 2010:

```
<!-- Note: Include this as a child of <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" ..> -->
<Directory Id="Office14DirectoryPathX64" Name="Office14X64"> <!-- Note: The Name attribute is redundant but needed to avoid ICE30 warning -->
  <Directory Id="Office14LibraryX64" Name="Library"/>
</Directory>
```

Useful references:
[How to detect installed version of MS-Office?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3266675/)
[How do you copy a set of files to multiple places using Wix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557933/)

Comment: I only just got back to this project and just saw your reply above. Thank you very much for your detailed response.

Comment: How can I get the path to the 64-bit installer for 64-bit Office?

Comment: @martinixs - Updated the answer to include a solution for the 64 bit version of Excel.

Comment: @bradfordrg Thanks so much for example, you very much helped me.