# Wix installer CopyFile move file not working

Tags: asp.net, wix, windows-installer

I want to move a file from one Directory to another and it simply does nothing.

Here is the part from my `Product.wxs`:

```
<Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="$(var.ProductName)" Level="1">
  <ComponentRef Id="testCopy"/>
</Feature>

<DirectoryRef Id="dirConfigs">
  <Component Id="web.config" Guid="8736259D-4FEE-4826-B109-76DD3B0EDAE7">
    <CopyFile Id="CopyWebConfig" 
              SourceProperty="dirProject"
              SourceName="Web.config"
              DestinationProperty="dirConfigs"
              DestinationName="Web.config"
              />
  </Component>
</DirectoryRef>

<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Directory Id="$(var.PlatformProgramFilesFolder)">
    <Directory Id="dirParent" Name="$(var.CustomerName)">
      <Directory Id="dirProject" Name="$(var.ProductName)">
        <Directory Id="dirConfigs" Name="$(var.ConfigFolderName)">
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Directory>
</Directory>
```

**Edit**
I also tried with Source/DestinationDirectory instead of Source/DestinationProperty
Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is generally easier to do file-copying on application launch instead of as part of the setup - not always possible for web apps. Application launch code is easier to implement, debug and change as you need to. Is that an option? [I have this old answer on CopyFile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1564006/129130). It looks like you are copying the file to the folder it is already in. Try changing `DestinationProperty="dirConfigs"` to `DestinationProperty ='DesktopFolder'`as a test?

Comment: Another approach that Christopher Painter has suggested: ["an override file" for web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49142733/129130).

Comment: @SteinÅsmul thanks for your comment! Copying to DesktopFolder wont work either, the CopyFile tag needs to be part of the File tag, unfortunately "an override file" for web.config is not applicable for us :/

Comment: I am not sure what happened during your testing, but you can try to find better samples on github.com. [Here is a "stored search"](https://github.com/search?q=%3CCopyFile+%3CWix+extension%3Awxs&type=Code). At the moment of writing, about 500+ hits.

Answer (score -2):

I would rely on a deferred CustomAction invoking the command line "copy" command rather than using CopyFile and execute it, like in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51010435/wix-deferred-custom-action-access-denied).

You'll need admin permissions if you are going to write the file in a protected folder or a folder requiring administrative access (on Windows Vista+, anything outside the %USER% folder.